# OpenIddict 5.2 Introspection rejected - Can't find any information as to why

Tags: openiddict

I'm getting the following response from the auth server on introspection:

```
info: OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher[0]
      The response was successfully returned as a JSON document: {
        "active": false
      }.
OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher: Information: The response was successfully returned as a JSON document: {
  "active": false
}.
```

I have Trace logging on to try and find WHY it's saying active = false (the token is active in the database)

How do one find out WHY introspection returned the result it did? I can't seem to intercept the introspection request like I can the others so I'm in the dark.